# Are addresses in Solana unique accross all the tokens?

Tags: spl-token, account, associated-token-account, spl-associated-token-account, address

I'm working on a system wherein there're multiple blockchains involved, and withing each one, native assets and tokens too are used together, as well as wallet addresses of them.

In Ethereum and TRON, for instance, a single address is used for a native token, as well as for USDT, USDT.  Looking at Solana, I see that it, on the other hand, has unique addresses. Or it may be that I've overlooked something.

Is this the case that each address in Solana is **absolutely** unique? For any token so too?

**update**

In my web application each user will have a Solana (SOL, USDT, USDC) wallet, among the wallets of a few other blockchains.

Does this mean that I could generate for each user either:

- a) one parent Solana address for every asset; or
- b) one parent Solana address and one token address **per asset**

.... and either (a) or (b) would work **equally** correct and fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Solana, your wallet has an address and then can have `N` many associated token accounts that also have their own unique addresses that are derived from the combination of the parent wallet's address and the address of the token mint.

You're able to send an SPL token to the parent wallet address and the token program is smart enough to deposit the token into the correct associated token account, however, each of them still have their own unique address.

---

**EDIT**

`(b)` would be correct in your updated example. Each asset have its own associated token account with its own address that is owned by the parental Solana wallet (which also has its own address).

In order for the smart routing that i described to work (sending SPL tokens to the parent wallet), the underlying associated token accounts must already exist for that token mint.

Comment: That means, it both: unique and non-unique, right?

Comment: look at my update please

Comment: @Kum updated my response